# Expressão regular que aceite letras, números e underline

Tags: php, regex

Como faço para que a ER abaixo aceite letras, números e underline, e continue não permitindo os demais caracteres?

```
preg_match('/[^a-z\d]/', $_POST['login'])
```

Answer (score 2):

Os colchetes (`[]`) definem uma [classe de caracteres](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), ou seja, aceita tudo que estiver dentro deles. Ex: `[ab]` significa "a letra `a` ou a letra `b`".

Mas quando o primeiro caractere dentro dos colchetes é um `^`, você estará negando o que tem dentro dele. Ex: `[^ab]` significa "qualquer coisa que não seja `a` nem `b`".

Por isso, ao fazer `[^a-z\d]`, você está rejeitando as letras minúsculas e os dígitos. Para aceitar letras, números e underline, você deve incluí-los nos colchetes e retirar o `^`, então ficaria `[A-Za-z0-9_]`.

Estou assumindo que você quer aceitar strings com mais de um caractere, então use o quantificador `+`, que significa "uma ou mais ocorrências". Então a expressão fica `[A-Za-z0-9_]+`.

Como esses são os únicos caracteres permitidos, use também `^` **fora** dos colchetes e no início da expressão, pois ele significa início da string, e no final coloque `$`, que significa o final da string. A expressão completa fica:

```
preg_match("/^[A-Za-z0-9_]+$/", $_POST['login'])
```

Ou seja: uma ou mais ocorrências (`+`) de letras, números ou underline (`[A-Za-z0-9_]`), do início (`^`) ao fim (`$`) da string.

Comment: \w = A-Za-z0-9_

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo `\w` pode incluir outros caracteres se estiver com a opção `u` (unicode) habilitada: https://ideone.com/GPumF9 - Tudo bem que nesse caso específico não faria diferença, pois não usei essa opção, mas de qualquer forma obrigado por me lembrar que o `\w` existe (às vezes eu esqueço desses atalhos) - outra coisa é que eu não lembro se no PHP o *locale* ou outras configurações do ambiente também podem influenciar no comportamento do `\w` (acho que é por isso que eu acabo não usando na maioria das vezes, porque nunca sei as regras exatas em cada linguagem).